How can I change the default text color of CKEditor 5 in Strapi 5?
I followed the documentation from https://market.strapi.io/plugins/@ckeditor-strapi-plugin-ckeditor and implemented CKEditor in my Strapi project, but the text is white. How can I change it to black?
Versions: Strapi 5, CKEditor 5
